# Set created_at when programatically creating a Magento order

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, date

I'm struggling to set the order date when creating a magento order programatically.

Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
$orderObj->setData('created_at', $date);
$orderObj->setUpdatedAt($date);
```

but it doesn't appear to work.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What value did it stored in the db NULL?

Comment: Try `setCreatedAt(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`created_at` and `updated_at` for orders is set in `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Abstract::_prepareDataForSave()`:

```
/**
 * Prepare data for save
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object
 * @return array
 */
protected function _prepareDataForSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    $currentTime = Varien_Date::now();
    if ((!$object->getId() || $object->isObjectNew()) && !$object->getCreatedAt()) {
        $object->setCreatedAt($currentTime);
    }
    $object->setUpdatedAt($currentTime);
    $data = parent::_prepareDataForSave($object);
    return $data;
}
```

You can see that `updated_at` is always set to the current time, whereas `created_at` is only set if the attribute is empty. The format that it should have comes from `Varien_Date`.

So you should be able to define your own creation timestamp:

```
$order->setCreatedAt(Varien_Date::formatDate($date, false));
```

where `$date` can be a Unix timestamp or an arbitrary date expression that can be parsed with PHPs [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime)

Comment: Does this not stop `created_at` being set when the object is not new also?

Comment: You had me for a moment. No, it only stops it from being automatically set when the object is new. You still can set it manually.

Comment: that is what I meant sorry. The problem may be that it is a new object and they are trying to set a data other than current date.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Yeah, so one actually has to save the order first, then change `created_at`, then save again.

Comment: I stand corrected (again). It will work, look at the parantheses!